# How does one return "war booty" to their rightful original owners?

Tags: military, vietnam-war

I honestly don't know where to ask this question, so here goes.

My grandfather served on the Communist side during the Vietnam War. He shot down an F-104 (or an F-4) and removed a piece of flight instrument from its wreckage.

I would like to return this instrument to the USAF/US government, but I don't know how.

How should I proceed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prize_of_war

Comment: You might get a decent answer on the [Law SE site](https://law.stackexchange.com/), or at least get some idea about the relevant laws/procedure (if any) for this sort of thing.

Comment: This is a nice sentiment from your part, but given that the item does not seem to be of particular artistic/historical(it is not "one of a kind") or sentimental(it is not a heirloom from a soldier) value, I doubt that there is actually a lot of interest in having it returned. You could just inquiry the USA embassy about it; as it was a part of government owned equipment. And perhaps in https://law.stackexchange.com they can tell you if USA laws give any indication of what to do.

Comment: There are likely some Vietnam war museums and/or air museums that would be interested in it, along with an expanded version of the story behind it.

Comment: Presumably this would be a matter for Vietnamese law, assuming that this event happened in Vietnam.   For the US view, I think this counts as [All enemy public movable property captured or found on a battlefield becomes the property of the capturing State](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/customary-ihl/eng/docs/v2_rul_rule49) as a flight instrument is pretty obviously not a personal possession of the pilot but rather is "enemy public property".